# SharpDevelop - resource managing and accessing problem

Tags: c#, .net, dll, resources, sharpdevelop

I have created C# WinForms project in SharpDevelop then i added DLL project and referenced it in WinForms main project and also put directive USING. and everything went fine, except in bumped into some problems...

I searched around the web for my problems, but i haven't found any solution - yet the closest one was this one, but still haven't resolved about 90% of things.

First one is for accessing resources:

https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/Using-Resources

Now:

**>1<**

How do i access resources in embedded RESX file in WinForms(sounds, images, other custom datatypes), i have put `Using` directive?

I tried like `Properties.Resources`(trying to use scheme like in VS2015)
But as i figured out it does the things for handling resources a little differently.

But how EXACTLY the code would look?

**>2<**

The second question is same thing, only difference is that i put resources in new empty DLL file, how do i access the image or audio from DLL (The DLL is already referenced in WinForms project and WinForms projects is already using `Using` directive, so that's not the problem)

And in formal what i am trying to do is this example: To play the sound in background of the WinForms program, this background sound is saved as resource in external DLL file, referenced to WinForms project and configured for use.
As a second part, there it is a image saved as resource in WinForms EXE file and i want to access it to set it to PictureBox control object like

```
Picturebox1.Image = Properties.Resources.SampleIMG   **(Note that is a line from Visual Studio, not working in SharpDevelop!)**
```

But no matter what i do, read on the web, try by myself there i find no solution to all that! Even the syntax of the Resource Managing and similar things are different from Visual Studio, so none of the syntaxes i want doesn't work!

Sorry for possible mispelling any word in English,

Thank you in advance,

Andrej

Comment: The wiki page you linked to is for files that are added as embedded resources in the project. If you have a resx file then the normal approach is to save the file so it generates an associated .cs file. This will then have code for how to access the information in the resource which will be embedded.

Comment: Matt Ward Thank You, that took me like 30 mins to figure it out about RESX in SharpDevelop.  But i also figured it out, that SharpDevelop should generate .CS files (clases) for each and every resource that you put in as 'Embedded', but here at my installment it does not generate the prerequired .cs files for resources, even if i use 'Public RESX generator' tool, that ships with SharpDevelop natively.